# How to make R use all processors?

Tags: linux, r, windows, parallel-processing, package

I have a quad-core laptop running Windows XP, but looking at Task Manager R only ever seems to use one processor at a time. How can I make R use all four processors and speed up my R programs?

Comment: Based on the comments below and a linkedin search of your name... I'm pretty sure that is shameless advertising (https://www.linkedin.com/in/dmsmith).  You answered your own question with a paid product in which you are involved in developing... come on...

Answer (score 45):

I have a basic system I use where I parallelize my programs on the "for" loops. This method is simple once you understand what needs to be done. It only works for local computing, but that seems to be what you're after.

You'll need these libraries installed:

```
library("parallel")
library("foreach")
library("doParallel")
```

First you need to create your computing cluster. I usually do other stuff while running parallel programs, so I like to leave one open. The "detectCores" function will return the number of cores in your computer.

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
registerDoParallel(cl, cores = detectCores() - 1)
```

Next, call your for loop with the "foreach" command, along with the %dopar% operator. I always use a "try" wrapper to make sure that any iterations where the operations fail are discarded, and don't disrupt the otherwise good data. You will need to specify the ".combine" parameter, and pass any necessary packages into the loop. Note that "i" is defined with an equals sign, not an "in" operator!

```
data = foreach(i = 1:length(filenames), .packages = c("ncdf","chron","stats"),
               .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
  try({
       # your operations; line 1...
       # your operations; line 2...
       # your output
     })
}
```

Once you're done, clean up with:

```
stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 29):

The [CRAN Task View on High-Performance Compting with R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) lists several options. XP is a restriction, but you still get something like [**snow**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=snow) to work using sockets within minutes.

Answer (score 16):

As of version 2.15, R now comes with native support for multi-core computations. Just load the  parallel package

```
library("parallel")
```

and check out the associated vignette

```
vignette("parallel")
```

Comment: Bootstrapping via package boot my also be of interest and is explained in that file.

Comment: @MistereeDevlord Ah thanks. Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 7):

I hear tell that [REvolution R](http://www.revolution-computing.com/campaign/100-percent-r-and-more.php?gclid=adgroup1&gclid=CPDv-7zJ4pwCFQi_sgodFVXPIg) supports better multi-threading then the typical CRAN version of R and REvolution also supports 64 bit R in windows. I have been considering buying a copy but I found their pricing opaque. There's no price list on their web site. Very odd.

Comment: If you have to ask the price, you can't afford it.

Comment: Academic pricing is listed here: http://www.revolution-computing.com/industry/academic.php .

Comment: It's been bought by Microsoft now, and there is no free academic version anymore. But you can install http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/revolution-r-open for free, and it also comes with the intel MKL libraries. On Windows if you take the libiomp5md.dll, Rblas.dll and Rlapack.dll files from that install and overwrite the ones in whatever R install you like to use you'll have multithreaded matrix operations (typically 10-20 x speedup). Or the Atlas Rblas.dll from https://prs.ism.ac.jp/~nakama/SurviveGotoBLAS2/binary/windows/x64/ als works and is almost as fast.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the `multicore` package works on XP. It gives some basic multi-process capability, especially through offering a drop-in replacement for `lapply()` and a simple way to evaluate an expression in a new thread (`mcparallel()`).

Comment: the drop in replacement for `lapply()` is called `mclapply()`. It's really that simple: N processors are N times faster (so long as all the heavy lifting is inside the function that's being applied)

Comment: the multicore package requires a POSIX compliant OS so it does not work in Win. You can read the requirements here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multicore/index.html

Comment: `doSMP` provides similar functionality to `multicore` on Windows, and is [available on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doSMP/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

On Windows I believe the best way to do this would probably be with foreach and snow as David Smith said.

However, Unix/Linux based systems can compute using multiple processes with the 'multicore' package.  It provides a high-level function, 'mclapply', that performs a list comprehension across multiple cores.  An advantage of the 'multicore' package is that each processor gets a private copy of the Global Environment that it may modify.  Initially, this copy is just a pointer to the Global Environment, making the sharing of variable extremely quick if the Global Environment is treated as read-only.

Rmpi requires that the data be explicitly transferred between R processes instead of working with the 'multicore' closure approach.

-- Dan

Answer (score 1):

If you do a lot of matrix operations and you are using Windows you can install [revolutionanalytics.com/revolution-r-open](http://revolutionanalytics.com/revolution-r-open) for free, and this one comes with the intel MKL libraries which allow you to do multithreaded matrix operations. On Windows if you take the libiomp5md.dll, Rblas.dll and Rlapack.dll files from that install and overwrite the ones in whatever R version you like to use you'll have multithreaded matrix operations (typically you get a 10-20 x speedup for matrix operations). Or you can use the Atlas Rblas.dll from [prs.ism.ac.jp/~nakama/SurviveGotoBLAS2/binary/windows/x64](http://prs.ism.ac.jp/~nakama/SurviveGotoBLAS2/binary/windows/x64) which also work on 64 bit R and are almost as fast as the MKL ones. I found this the single easiest thing to do to drastically increase R's performance on Windows systems. Not sure why they don't come as standard in fact on R Windows installs.

On Windows, multithreading unfortunately is not well supported in R (unless you use [OpenMP via Rcpp](https://wbnicholson.wordpress.com/2014/07/10/parallelization-in-rcpp-via-openmp/)) and the available [SOCKET-based parallelization on Windows systems, e.g. via package parallel, is very inefficient. On POSIX systems things are better as you can use forking there.](http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/) (package `multicore` there is I believe the most efficient one). You could also try to use package `Rdsm` for multithreading within a shared memory model - I've got a version on my github that has unflagged -unix only flag and should work also on Windows (earlier Windows wasn't supported as dependency `bigmemory` supposedly didn't work on Windows, but now it seems it does) :

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github('tomwenseleers/Rdsm')
library(Rdsm)
```