# R, change column type in a dataframe

Tags: r, excel

i am using this code to read multiple excel file from a folder

```
library(readxl)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
library(dplyr)
df <- bind_rows(df.list, .id = "id")
```

I am getting this error

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Can not automatically convert from numeric to character in column "c14"
```

.

the column C14 is a mixtures, in some files is only numeric and others is text,

is there a way to tell R that c14 should be text.

thanks.

Comment: It's hard to help you when we don't know the data types of the other columns or the number of columns. If you know the number of columns, you can do `df.list <- lapply(file.list, function(x) read_excel(x, col_types = rep("text", num_cols)))`; where `num_cols` is the number of columns. Once you have your list of dataframes, you can edit it to change the data types to their appropriate types. But if you know the data types of the other columns, you can just use a character vector of the data types with the `col_types` parameter.

Comment: thanks, they are 46 columns, i want everything to be text, as the purpose of this exercise is just to consolidate multiple excel file into one csv that will be further processed into PowerQuery

Comment: Then try `df.list <- lapply(file.list, function(x) read_excel(x, col_types = rep("text", 46)))`.

Comment: got this error    Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  Need one name and type for each column

Comment: That may be a bug that has been reported [here](https://github.com/hadley/readxl/issues/81). My best bet is that the column after your last column (after C46) is being read by the `read_excel` function.

Comment: Yea, that's definitely the issue. I will write this an answer and you can accept it when you get a chance.

Comment: can you please write your first reply as an answer, it was my mistake the toal number was 45, there was a dummy column with "."   df.list <- lapply(file.list, function(x) read_excel(x, col_types = rep("text", num_cols)))

Comment: I just added it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that you are letting the `read_excel` function guess the data types of your excel files. But the function does not always get it right. In this case, it seems like there is a column in one or more of your files that contains a mixture of numeric and character values. Because of that, the guessing is kind of failing to get it right. There are two ways to remedy this:

First, if you know the number of columns in each file you can do:

```
df.list <- lapply(file.list, function(x) read_excel(x, col_types = rep("text", num_cols)))
```

where `num_cols` is the number of columns. Once you have your list of dataframes, you can edit it to change the data types to their appropriate types.

Second, if you know the data types of the other columns, you can just use a character vector of the data types with the `col_types` parameter.

#### Edit:

It seems that you have 45 columns in each of your files, so you can just do:

```
df.list <- lapply(file.list, function(x) read_excel(x, col_types = rep("text", 45)))
```

If you ever get the following error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Need one name and type for each
>   column

Please make sure to go back and check to make sure that you actually have the same number of columns that you have mentioned in your script. This error indicates that the length of the vector of column types (`col_types`) does not match the length of the vector of column names (`col_names`).

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, trying to learn R, just to avoid powerquery limitation, no export to csv :)

Comment: I am not familiar with powerquery but I will make sure to take a look. Thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: when i add bigger excel file i get this error  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : std::bad_alloc

Comment: This is a memory allocation issue. It basically means that `readxl` failed to allocate enough memory for the data you are importing. Are you using a machine with somewhat limited capacities, like a virtual machine?

Comment: it is a laptop with 8 GA of Ram, the files are big, some of them 70 MG.

Comment: You may want to use multiple cores on your machine. R, by default, only uses one core of your machine. Try using packages like `snow` or `parallel`. Take a look at [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395309/how-to-make-r-use-all-processors).