# If matched, return substring (run time issue)

Tags: r, string, parallel-processing, doparallel, parallel-foreach

I have the below df:

```
df <- data.table(search_term = c('weather', 'tesla battery', 'apple juice')); df
 
     search_term
1:       weather
2: tesla battery
3:   apple juice
```

Say, I own a fruit store and am looking to label each search term for further analysis.

```
# target string (products I sell)
x <- paste(c('apple', 'orange'), collapse = "|"); x

[1] "apple|orange"

# extract from search term
df[, product := str_extract(search_term, x)][]

     search_term product
1:       weather    <NA>
2: tesla battery    <NA>
3:   apple juice   apple
```

The above achieves my goal. However, given I have hundreds of thousands of (unique) search terms and again, hundreds of thousands of (unique) products the current run time is prohibitively long (approx 24 hrs).

I have also tried @hangmanwa7id 's [parallel running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395309/how-to-make-r-use-all-processors) method:

```
library("parallel")
library("foreach")
library("doParallel")

# create your computing cluster
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
registerDoParallel(cl, cores = detectCores() - 1)

# assign batch number
x <- 10            # no. of batches
y <- nrow(df)      # nrow
z <- round(y / x)  # no. of rows per batch
df[, batch := rep(1:x, each=z, length.out=y)]

# target string
a <- paste(c('apple', 'orange'), collapse = "|")

# parallel computing
c = foreach(i = df[, sort(unique(batch))]
               , .packages = c("data.table", "stringr")
               , .combine = rbind
            ) %dopar%
  {
    b <- df[batch == i]
    b[, product := str_extract(search_term, a)]
  }

# stop hoarding cluster
stopCluster(cl)
```

but perhaps `str_extract` cannot be parallelised, the run time is similar

Ultimately, may I ask if any means such as below are possible in achieving lower run times?

1. using a function other than `str_extract`
2. Other ways of parallel running

Thank you

Comment: have you tried grepl to check for an initial match and then extracting the sub-string that does match from the reduced set of results in a second stage? Also I think you might be better off parallelizing over target strings than search terms.

Comment: True. That will reduce rows processed, thus, run time. Thank you.